# Difference in the amount of heat produced in two circuits having two different metals

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

There are two circuits to the first nichrome is connected like this
[image]

and in the other a copper wire instead of the nichrome wire when electricity is passed through which wire gets more heated? Since resistance is more in nichrome it has to be nichrome that should get more heated right? heat is the product of I,R and T and I will be more in copper since it has low resistance so which one will be it an explained answer will be more appreciated

Comment: You'll get a better response if you show what you have tried and identify exactly where you are "stuck."

Comment: @CarlWitthoft which one will produce more heat the nichrome circuit or the copper circuit? Chances are more for nichrome since it has more resistance but as resistance increases intensity decreases and intensity is an important factor in heat right? so how would it be?

Comment: I've never seen the word "intensity" used in electronics.  Perhaps you need to read some introductory info on the theory of electric circuits?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft intensity of current (I)

Comment: Are the resistances of the two wires the same?  Are we to assume the dry cells are ideal. (no internal resistance.) Should we take the temperature coefficient (change in resisitivity with temperature.) of the two metals into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to cite @CarlWitthoft from the comments. Intensity is not a term used in electric circuits. Intensity of current would not make any sense. However, I can vaguely make out what you are trying to ask:

What you are trying to say is: "Two circuits are identical to the one in the figure, except for the fact that one has a nichrome wire and the other has a copper wire. Now, 
1) the wires get heated as current passes and Nichrome, having a higher resistance than copper should get heated more. 
2) But since copper has a lower resistance, it will admit more flow of current, so copper should get heated more."

Point two is invalid for your calculation. You can think of it intuitively as this. For the same amount of current entering both the wires, since copper has lower resistance, it will not impede the motion of the electrons. However, since nichrome has higher resistance, there is more energy loss in as the current passes through this wire. This energy loss manifests as heat.

Your second argument is therefore flawed. You should know that the same amount of current flows in both wires and that the amount of energy loss is higher in the nichrome wire.

Comment: If the nichrome wire is replaced with a copper wire, the diagram will show a short circuit.  In this case more current will flow, and more heat will be dissipated.